# differential equation for oscillatory phase

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

The differential equation $$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + k x = 0$$ leads to harmonic solution like $x = \sin(\omega t + \phi)$.  Is there a differential equation that leads to a harmonic solution with harmonic phase, like $x = \sin(\omega_a t + \sin(\omega_b t + \phi_b))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by taking the first and second derivatives of your solution:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\sin(\omega_a t + \sin(\omega_b t + \phi_b))=(\omega_b \cos(\omega_b t+\phi_b)+\omega_a)\cos(\sin(\omega_b t+\phi_b)+\omega_at)\\\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\sin(\omega_a t + \sin(\omega_b t + \phi_b))=
−(\omega_b \cos(\omega_b t+\phi_b)+\omega_a)^2\sin(\sin(\omega_b t+\phi_b)+\omega_at)−b^2\sin{(\omega_b t+\phi_b)}\cos(\sin(\omega_b t+\phi_b)+\omega_at)$$

Replacing the sin-sin term with $x$ and the cos-sin term with an expression of $dx/dt$, we can now write $$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=−(\omega_b \cos(\omega_b t+\phi_b)+\omega_a)^2 x−\frac{\omega_b^2\sin{(\omega_b t+\phi_b)}}{\omega_b \cos(\omega_b t+\phi_b)+\omega_a}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

You might be able to simplify it, but this is an example of the differential equation that you were looking for

Comment: Thank you.  There is a physics interpretation, or application, for this equation.  The goal is to extract the time dependent phase component.  Now I need a rapid numerical scheme to estimate wa, wb, and phib from the measured data.  An alternative interpretation of the physical process is to let the phase be constant but the frequency is harmonic.

Comment: I can think of an example where the frequency is harmonic. Suppose you have a guitar string, you fix one end of it, lay it horizontally across a table, make it go over a pulley, and hang a weight on the other end. The frequency of the oscillations is dependent on the tension in the string. Let the weight on the string oscillate, like a small pendulum

Comment: Also, a ship in waves, the wave encounter frequency depends on the ship speed.  But the ship speed varies with the slope of the wave, so the encounter frequency varies.  The variation can be modeled as a variation in phase.